# Request shows column name in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I develop my site with PHP, MySQL and I want to list a column name of my table translate.

I have written this code and it ain't working.

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = translate;
```

This code works in MySQL but returns the name of the column in double, And it doesn't work in PHP.

This is my php code:

```php
try{
    $bdd -> new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'root',       '');
  }catch (Exception $e)
  {
      die('Erreur: ' . $e->getMessage());
  }

  $req -> $bdd -> prepare('SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                     WHERE TABLE_NAME = translate;');
  $req->execute();
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any PHP code so we can't really say. Check for errors.

Comment: Okay i want to put my code php

Comment: translate needs to be in single quotes (unless translate is a variable - you don't say)

Comment: I place translate in a single quotes but it isn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully<br>';

$sql = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["Field"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

My Table is:-

[image]

Output is:-

[image]

Comment: In mysql the column_name repeat double.

Comment: @BigWatanga Please check update answer. It's work for me.

Comment: I don't try this because i don't want to use mysqli_connect to connect with my database  but i create a new table and put the translate language in the table, it is very easy and resolve my problem.